Use Loophole static hostname with another account
I have used a static hostname with my Loophole account
loophole http 7777 --hostname testhostname

I stopped this loophole session and loged out of my account. Now I want to use the same static hostname from another account but I get an error. It looks that the hostname is associated with my previous account as the following line works just fine:
loophole http 7777 --hostname testhostname2

How can I disassociate the static hostname from my previous account that I could use it with a new account. I do not see any relevant loophole commands and no information on loophole.cloud website
